# Convert null as string to real null

Tags: sql, sql-server, dynamic-programming

I'm using and looking to use this string as a dynamic insert into a table. The string will be a column name.

Ex. LineText =

```
SELECT '1','731289','NULL','123.45','0','123.45','BUYER','101017000000','NULL','Rachael','Henderson','NULL','NULL','5/28/2020 17:00','MC','************5454','API','Integration Gateway','anonymous','Accepted','Approved','Sent','0000000-0000-00000-00000-0000000000 '
```

Can someone help me with replacing ,`',NULL,'`, with `,NULL,`. Having difficulties. I do not want to insert string values containing NULL I want the actual column to be NULL as the insert value into the table

Looking to use

```
Select LineText = Replace(LineText, (need help) )
```

Comment: Use parameters, not strings, for this purpose.

Comment: i need to use the string as it is the information the vendor supplies @gordonlinoff

Comment: @JohnCappelletti I need 'NULL' to represent an actually NULL value that you would insert into a column. Ex. Column DOG varchar (10) will display NULL instead of string value `'NULL'`

Comment: `replace(LineTxt,'''null''', 'null')`?

Comment: @DaleK GENIUS ! ty

Answer (score 2):

Just replace the string, `'null'` with an actual `null` using replace, noting that to escape single quotes you double them e.g.

```
replace(LineTxt,'''null''', 'null')
```

Answer (score -1):

How about `ISNULL(colName, 'NULL')` ?